# Navigating through Github repos

Tags: python, github

I am currently trying to find end-to-end speech recognition solutions to implement in python (I am a data science student btw). I have searched for projects on github and find it very hard to comprehend how these repositories work and how I can use them for my own project.

I am mainly confused with the following:

- how do repositories usually get used by other developers and how can I use them best for my specific issue?
- How do I know if the proposed solution is working in python?
- What is the usual process in installing the project from the repo?

Sorry for the newbie question but I am fairly new to this. 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> how do repositories usually get used by other developers and how can I use them best for my specific issue?

The best way to get started with GitHub is to review the [documentation](https://guides.github.com/activities/hello-world/).

> How do I know if the proposed solution is working in python?

Every repository includes a monochrome / colorful line between the caption and the code section. On clicking this line, you can see the languages of the current project (here is the example for [Tensorflow](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow))
[image]

> What is the usual process in installing the project from the repo?

Usually the project installation and usage steps are described in [README.md](https://help.github.com/en/github/creating-cloning-and-archiving-repositories/about-readmes) file that should be attached to GitHub repository. This assumes installed `git` and basic knowledge of its commands.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the documentation(README.md) there you can have all the information you need.

You can install the project from a repo by cloning or by downloading zip.